# SDRAM timing confusion

Tags: sdram, timing-analysis

I'm looking at this data sheet: T67M-512Mb-Mobile-Lpddr-Sdram (targeting speed grade -75) and trying to understand the timing requirements for performing a read, specifically when to sample the DQ input data lines. It gives a formula on page 27 for Data valid output window (DVW) being `tQH - tDQSQ`

Writing down the min and max values as `<min,max>` in unit of nanoseconds, I find `tDQSQ` on page 26 as `<-,0.6>` . I assume if the minimum is not stated, the worst case is 0?

A formula is given for `tQH` on page 27 as `tHP-tQHS`. `tQHS` is on page 27 and given as `<-,0.75>` while yet another formula is given for `tHP` as `tCH,tCL`. Not sure what a comma means here.

`tCH` and `tCL` are both found on page 26 with values of `<0.45,0.55>`

Plugging in all my values, I get a final formula of:

`(<0.45, 0.55> - <0.0, 0.75>) - <0.0, 0.6>`

This formula confuses me as there are values within the ranges that can result in an overall valid window time of zero, or even a negative value.

Am I calculating/interpreting this correct? Do these values means that there are no gaurantees that the output data will be valid?

Answer (score 1):

After more research, it looks like the values *could* be negative. Relative to the clock, the data valid window can slide all around. To overcome this interfacing difficulty, the part includes a "data strobe" which has matched latencies with the data. Relative to this data strobe, the valid window has a much more consistent and reliable timing. Interfacing with this part would most likely require using the data strobe the clock in the data into the receiving registers.